# Поворот угла у объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, помогите разобраться с углом вращения объекта.
На текущий момент реализовано вращение объекта.
Хочу сделать что бы вращалась стрелка и угол поворота зависел от текущих координат X и Y. Unity2D.

```
    public float angle = 0; // угол 
    public float radius = 0.5f; // радиус
    public bool isCircle = false; // условие движения по кругу
    public float speed = 5f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        angle += Time.deltaTime; // меняется значение угла
        var x = Mathf.Cos(angle * speed) * radius + parent.position.x;
        var y = Mathf.Sin(angle * speed) * radius + parent.position.y;

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y,0);
        //transform.Rotate(0, 0, a);
    }
```

Слева как сейчас (не вращается), а нужно как справа (вращается и смотрит в 1 сторону всегда), но не знаю как рассчитать градусы для вращения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для функций `Cos` и `Sin` угол должен быть в **РАДИАНАХ**, а не градусах! `Rotate` в кватернионах, а для привычные градусы это `localEulerAngles`.

Comment: Вращение происходит корректно, но не знаю как рассчитать градусы для вращения объекта (что бы всегда смотрел наружу)

Comment: можете попробовать LookAt (слежение за объектами), тогда ваш прямоугольник будет следить за центром круга по которому вращается, если у вас там ничего нет (объекта) то добавьте туда EmptyObject и привяжите к нем (сделайте его отслеживающим объектом) по идеи ваш прямоугольник будет отслеживать его и поворачиваться. Напишите если помогло или нет, попробуем найти ответ

Comment: Астроном, спасибо большое, попробую lookat как буду перед компьютером. Объект в центре есть - персонаж. О результатах отпишусь.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, объект пропал из вида, base111.gif - как было / base222.gif - c lookatо [https://disk.yandex.ru/d/O1V7zKikXU1ICQ]

Comment: Пробовал использовать через угол Эйлера, но что-то не получилось, поворот не синхронизированный  `alpha = Mathf.Atan2(y , x)* Mathf.Rad2Deg; transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0 ,0, alpha));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось достичь вращения объекта (код ниже)
LookAt в Unity2D не получилось сделать, смещается в 3D объект, из-за чего не видно.

```
Vector2 direction = parent.position - transform.position;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, direction);
```